# Accessing resources in Private Grails Plugin web-app

Tags: file, grails, plugins, private

I have a main grails application that use a private Grails plugin mySearch.
the plugin Search has a file in Search\web-app\filters.json.

when the application is run with run-app : the ressource file can be accessed with :

```
def ressource = new File( org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.GrailsPluginUtils.getPluginDirForName('mySearch')?.file?.absolutePath
+"/web-app/filters.json").text
```

but It doesn't work when the app is deployed in tomcat7.

I'have tried using `pluginManager.getGrailsPlugin('mySearch')`

but I can't access the obsolute path of the resource.

Comment: Try prepending the following, provided you have said system property set: (grails.util.Environment.warDeployed ? System.getProperty('catalina.home') + '/webapps/myAppName/WEB-INF/ : '')

Comment: That won't work if the war isn't exploded

Comment: hello, the System.getProperty('catalina.home') give me the path to catalina home, not the path to root of the webapps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many attempts to resolve it, I found this workaround.
It looks messy but I didn't found anything else shorter and sweeter :

```
// work only for a plugin installed in app deployed from a war.
String getRessourceFile(String relativePath) throws FileNotFoundException{ 

    def pluginDir = pluginManager.getGrailsPlugin('MyPlugin')?.getPluginPath()
    def pluginFileSystemName = pluginManager.getGrailsPlugin('MyPlugin')?.getFileSystemName()

    def basedir = grailsApplication.parentContext.getResource("/")?.file
    if(basedir.toString().endsWith("web-app")){
        basedir = basedir.parent
    }

    ressourcefile = "$basedir$pluginDir/$relativePath"
    ressource = new File(ressourcefile)?.text
}
```